# iText7 - How to set up LoggerFactory?

Tags: .net, vb.net, itext

I just started using iText today so I started by running the example in Tutorial #1. Unfortunately I get these error messages:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.NullReferenceException' in itext.io.dll
iText.IO.Log.LoggerFactory: No logger factory was bound. Defaulting to no-operation logger implementation.
iText.IO.Log.LoggerFactory: In order to bind a logger factory use     iText.IO.Log.LoggerFactory.BindFactory().
```

Obviously I haven't set up something called LoggerFactory.  How do I do that?

Comment: in a comment below the answer you mention that you find the documentation incoherent. I asked you for specific feedback but unfortunately I haven't heard back from you yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We ran into a similar situation with a C# iText7 project, where

```
iText.IO.Log.LoggerFactory: No logger factory was bound. Defaulting to no-operation logger implementation.
iText.IO.Log.LoggerFactory: In order to bind a logger factory use     iText.IO.Log.LoggerFactory.BindFactory().
```

...would be logged every time we tried to run the process, as soon as we tried to access any iText classes.

We got around this by adding the following code to the beginning of our program:

```
iText.IO.Log.NoOpLoggerFactory iTextLoggerFactory = new iText.IO.Log.NoOpLoggerFactory();
iText.IO.Log.LoggerFactory.BindFactory(iTextLoggerFactory);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm finally getting back to this part of my project.  Yes, that solves the problem while noting that one has to import iText.IO.Log to allow that code to work.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! Updated to include iText.IO.Log...., so the import is not needed, though the import would definitely work.

Answer (score 1):

In the java version of iText, log4j is used to handle error-message logging.
In the the .net version log4net is used.
Normally, dependency-resolution is taken care of automatically if you install iText using NuGet.

Comment: I did install using NuGet but apparently no completely.  To be honest, after working with it for a couple of days, I have given up.  The documentation is just incoherent.

Comment: @SezMe Can you please give some more specific feedback about the documentation so it can be improved? What exactly are you missing?

Comment: 1. Examples in C# are sorely lacking.  2. There is no apparent organization at all.  3. I could find no beginner's tutorial at all.  4. There are lots of snippets (which is good) but few, if any, complete examples.

Comment: 1. The iText codebase gets ported from Java to .Net. Great effort is taken to ensure all classes have the same name, same methods, and same signature. You should be able to take any of the Java examples and run them as .net (adjusting uppercase/lowercase on method names, and not including system-related IO).
2. iText covers almost the entire pdf spec. It's very hard to neatly organize all content into disjunct categories. That being said, the search functionality on our website could do with improvements.

Comment: 3. There's a Jumpstart tutorial for iText7. Should work perfectly.
4. Most (if not all) of the code-samples are run as tests on Jenkins (that's why the accompanying files are sometimes prefixed with "cmp_"). These examples should be self-contained.

Comment: In any case, thank you for your feedback about the .NET documentation. Were Joris' comments helpful for you? And if so, what can we do to make it easier to find for other .NET developers like you who are looking for the same documentation? In other words, what would be the "principle of least surprise" for you in terms of iText documentation?

Comment: This is going beyond the scope of what we can do on Stack Overflow. If you want, I can set you up with an account on our Slack so we can discuss this in more detail.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse  Based on the comments above, yes I'd like you to do that.  In return, I'll give iText7 another go.

Comment: @JorisSchellekens  I've run through the Jumpstart any number of times and THINK I understand it at that level.  As I mention above, I'll start working with iText7 again to see if I can make a go of it.

Comment: @SezMe send an email to community@itextpdf.com, mentioning this Slack Overflow question, and I will set you up with an account.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are looking for a sample implementation, this is one we did for console logging:

```
public class ConsoleLoggerFactory : iText.IO.Log.ILoggerFactory
{
    private readonly iText.IO.Log.ILogger _logger = new ConsoleLogger();

    public iText.IO.Log.ILogger GetLogger( Type type )
    {
        return _logger;
    }

    public iText.IO.Log.ILogger GetLogger( string name )
    {
        return _logger;
    }
}
```

And here's the logger used by the above factory:

```
public sealed class ConsoleLogger : iText.IO.Log.ILogger
{
    public void Warn( string message )
    {
        Console.WriteLine( message );
    }

    public bool IsWarnEnabled()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void Trace( string message )
    {
        Console.WriteLine( message );
    }

    public bool IsTraceEnabled()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void Debug( string message )
    {
        Console.WriteLine( message );
    }

    public bool IsDebugEnabled()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void Info( string message )
    {
        Console.WriteLine( message );
    }

    public bool IsInfoEnabled()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void Error( string message, Exception exception )
    {
        Console.WriteLine( message );
        Console.WriteLine( exception );
    }

    public bool IsErrorEnabled()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void Error( string message )
    {
        Console.WriteLine( message );
    }
}
```

You can then bind it with the following code in your start-up:

```
var iTextLoggerFactory = new ConsoleLoggerFactory();
iText.IO.Log.LoggerFactory.BindFactory(iTextLoggerFactory);
```